# Stop keyboard from automatically waking up PC from sleep

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, sleep

I'm using Windows 7 x64.
Keyboard is Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600.

When I put my PC in sleep mode, it immediately wakes up automatically. I know it is the keyboard that does this because when I uncheck the boxes under Power Management Tab of the Device Manager, it no longer wakes up from sleep automatically.

However, I want to be able to wake up the PC from sleep by pressing a button on the keyboard.

Comment: Does the same keyboard cause the same issue on another PC?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have another PC to test this with. I have a laptop with Linux would it be relevant to test on it?

Comment: If it has sleeping mechanism similar to Windows then maybe yes. Otherwise, maybe you can consider taking the keyboard to work or to a friend. Behavior of keyboard with other PC should allow you to learn whether the problem is in the keyboard or in your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command powercfg -lastwake to view why your computer wake up automatically. 
You can also check the Event Viewer to ensure if it is caused by the keyboard.
https://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/

Comment: powercfg -lastwake says:
  
Wake History Count - 1  
Wake History [0]  
Wake Source Count - 1  
Wake Source [0]  
Type: Device  
Instance Path: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_8C31&SUBSYS_204A8086&REV_04\3&1158365 9&0&A0  
Friendly Name:  
Description: Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller  
Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation

Comment: Event Viewer says:
Wake Source: Device -Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller